# Find a $\mathbb F_p$ such that all polynomials doesn't has a root in it.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $f_1,\cdots,f_r$ be a set of monic irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$. Can we find a prime number $p$ such that no $f_i$ has a root in $\Bbb F_p$?

I have thought about the density, and I know that: for any $i$, the set $p$ such that $f_i$ splits in $\Bbb F_p$ has density $\frac{1}{2}$. But the density is too large, so I don't know how to get the result.

I'm OK with algebraic number theory and basic analytic number theory, hence the methods using these two are welcome.

Comment: I feel like I've seen this here before, so it's probably a duplicate.  Anyway, the idea is: for example, since $\left(\frac{6}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)$, at least one of 2, 3, or 6 is a quadratic residue (mod $p$).  In other words, at least one of $x^2 - 2$, $x^2 - 3$, $x^2 - 6$ has a root in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: As written, your question is unclear. Is the condition that *none* of the $f_i$ has a root in $\mathbb{F}_p$, or that *not all* of the $f_i$ have a root in $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: @Aphelli Non of the $f_i$ has a root in $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Good point. Thanks!

Comment: Use quadratic reciprocity to get congruences conditions on $p$ so that $f_i$ doesn't have a root $\bmod p$. Sometimes the congruences conditions contradict each other (if $x^2-2,x^2-3$ have no root $\bmod p$ then $x^2-6$ has one), if they don't then the $p$ such that no $f_i$ has a root will have at least density $2^{-r}$.